# Change the bar plot by using a dropdown menu (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drop-down-menu, bar-chart

I am essentially trying to create a bar chart that uses the specific csv data:

```
Country Name, Continent, Currency, Population, Capital, GDP, % Christian, % Muslim, % Jewish, % Hindu , % Buddhist, % Other
Afghanistan, Asia, afghani, 37170000, Kabul, 19360000000, 0 , 99.7 , 0, .01 , .01, .01
...
Zimbabwe, Africa, dollar,14862924, Harare,31000000000, .85, .10, .04,.02, .01, 0
```

So above is how the csv data will look like with all the countries around the world.

I essentially want to plot all the countries in a bar chart and essentially choose a specific variable in a dropdown menu and it essentially changes the bar chart. For example, I want to look at the specific variables of GDP and Population. These variables are within the drop down menu. When I click population, it shows the population of each country and when I click GDP, the Y axis changes to reflect this and the bars show the GDP. In the population bar graph, I also want to include the percentage of religions as a stacked bar chart. So the population bar is divided by the religion essentially.

```
var graph = document.getElementById('graph');
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 40},
        width = 2000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var svg = d3.select(graph)
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    d3.csv("countries.csv", function(data){
      data.forEach(function(d){
          d['Population'] = +d['Population']
          d['GDP'] = +d['GDP'];
      });
      var maxPop = d3.max(data, d => d['Population']);
      var maxGDP = d3.max(data, d => d['GDP']);
      var variables = ["Population", "GDP"]
      var countryNames = data.map(function(d) { return d['Country Name']; })
      d3.select(graph)
        .append('p')
        .append('select')
        .selectAll('option')
        .data(variables)
        .enter().append("option")
        .text(function (d) { return d; })
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
      var countryAxis = d3.scaleBand().range([10, width ]).domain(countryNames).padding(0.2);
      svg.append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(d3.axisBottom(countryAxis))
         .selectAll("text")
         .style("text-anchor", "end")
         .style("text-anchor", "start");
      var yAxis = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, maxPop]).range([ height, 0]);
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis y").attr("transform", "translate (" + 50 + " 0)")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis));
      svg.selectAll(".bar")
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append("rect")
         .attr("x", function(d) { return countryAxis(d['Country Name']); })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return yAxis(d['Population']); })
         .attr("width", countryAxis.bandwidth())
         .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yAxis(d['Population']); })
         .attr("fill", "#FF0000")

      });
```

This code helps make the bar graph essentially and the drop down menu but I do not know how to be able to update the bar graph when I click a specific drop down menu option and it changes the bar graph entirely. Meaning that when I click population it should show a stacked bar chart where the population is divided by the religions, and when GDP is selected it is essentially a regular bar chart and changing it back and forth. I want it all in D3. I have been using this as reference, but I am struggling to understand still

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_button_data_csv.html

Thanks.